# jQuery.backgroundPosition plug in - TypeError: $.curCSS is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-position

I use jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2 + jQuery UI 1.10.4 + Alexander Farkas BackgroundPosition v. 1.22.

It cause an error in firebug:

TypeError: $.curCSS is not a function

Any help?
As far as I checked this plug in, there is this function declared.

I have no idea, what's wrong.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

curCSS is the older version of css function in jQuery. So you can replace curCSS with css and it will solve the problem.